# how to Post Json Data to URL..?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, json.net

i'm new to wp8 and i don't have any idea to post and update my data in URL so please can any one help me to post/Update data in the url..

```
my header and content type...

Header - Accept: application/json
Content-Type application/json


MY Class Register with the variables... 

 public class Register 
    {
        public string email { get; set; }

        public string password { get; set; }
    }
```

My Design..

[image]

when i click ADD button it should post the data in my url.. so plz help me to do it..

MY CODE for post method..

```
              WebClient client = new WebClient();

              Register res = new Register();
              res.email = txt_email.Text;
              res.password = txt_password.Text;
              String json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);


               client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
               client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

               client.UploadStringCompleted += (object source, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs ex) =>
                 {
                     if (ex.Error != null || ex.Cancelled)
                      {
                         // Error or cancelled
                          MessageBox.Show(ex.Result);
                      }
                  };
               var uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
            //  client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
              client.UploadStringAsync(uri,json);  // message is the json content in string
```

ERROR.. on Adding content..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use RestSharp in my projects for that kind of thing. It simplifies things a bit particularly if you want to access cookies.

There's some examples on their wiki that should show you what to do.

http://restsharp.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebClient

```
public void PostJSON()
{
    client = new WebClient();

    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

        client.UploadStringCompleted += (object source, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null || e.Cancelled)
            {
                // Error or cancelled
            }
        };

        client.UploadStringAsync(url, message);  // message is the json content in string
}
```

Comment: Thanx Ritesh.. but im unable to add my json data here it shows me error.. can u plz say vat to do it... i had updated it in my post plz check it..

Comment: i had corrected the error.. but im getting an error at run time..plz check my post..

Comment: can you please state the line where the error is occurring. also provide stack trace

Comment: i think the exception might be due to webexception related with the server response. In UploadStringCompleted method if e.Error is not null, then cast it as WebException to get more details about response from server.

Comment: You will always get exception at that place because that statement is only reached either if there was an exception in response or the webrequest was cancelled. In either case Result property's value will not be valid. As i mention in previous comment, cast ex.error as Webexception to get exact response.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems legit to me. Since you get the error at runtime, I doubt that you might not have a proper Internet connection in your emulator. Or, if you are running your web service from localhost, you must help your emulator reach your local service.

**Case #1: No proper Internet connection**

Refer the following link and troubleshoot your network problem as stated in the MSDN page.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681694(v=vs.105).aspx

**Case #2: Help emulator to connect to a local web service**

Even when you can connect to external web content, you still need to configure your emulator to access your local web service. Go through the MSDN article given at the link below.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580(v=vs.105).aspx

Feel free to leave a comment if you need further assistance.

Comment: As I told, I cannot see any mistake in the code you provided. Just confirm me if your emulator can connect to the Internet and you have properly configured your emulator to connect to your local (I assume) web service.

Comment: What about the second case? Check if you can access your local web service.

Comment: sry actually i'm working with VS2012 For Windows Phone Case:2 option is un available to me..